# Cumulative Frequency based on row indices

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been having trouble with this problem for a while. So here's a sample data I am working with

```
dt <- data.frame(purchase_freq =  c('1','2','3','4', '5'), count = c('6','2','5','9','11'))
```

and I want it to have a result similar to this

```
dt <- data.frame(purchase_freq = c('1','2','3','4', '5'), count = c('6','2','5','9','11'), cumulative_index = ('33','27','25','20','11'))
```

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Sorry this was not clear enough. Basically cumulative_index[1] = count[1:5], cumulative_index[2]=count[2:5], cumulative_index[3]=count[3:5] and so forth. I know this might be simple enough but I cannot really solve this one. Appreciate all the help

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to compute, can you explain furthermore ?

Comment: Sorry, im not quite familiar in stackoverflow but basically,  c3[1] =33 is the sum of all c2 = 33, then c3[2] is the sum of c2[2:5] = 27 and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract sum of `c2` value with the cumulative sum of `c2`.

```
transform(dt, c3 = sum(c2) - c(0, cumsum(c2[-nrow(dt)])))

#  c1 c2 c3
#1  1  6 33
#2  2  2 27
#3  3  5 25
#4  4  9 20
#5  5 11 11
```

Can be written in `dplyr` and `data.table` as well :

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% mutate(c3 = sum(c2) - lag(cumsum(c2), default = 0))

library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, c3 := sum(c2) - shift(cumsum(c2), fill = 0)]
```

**data**

```
dt <- data.frame(c1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), c2 = c(6,2,5,9,11))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You really made it seem really easy. First time learning about lag and cumsum. Appreciate all the help